# Query formula Google Sheets with time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Does anyone know how I can add to the below query to find results between 2 time periods and sort from earliest to oldest.

'"&B5&"' in the query = MONDAY.
P in TempCSV is time from splitting date & time in column D with this formula in column O =iferror(split(D2, " ")) and this continues down the column for all other rows.
I cant use date and time from D as the date is creation date and not current date in relation to what I'm trying to achieve.

```
=query(TempCSV,"Select A,D where A contains 'Something' and A contains 'Anotherthing' and C contains '"&B5&"' **where P >=05:00:00 and P <=12:00:00**")
```

I have successfully got the following to work in another range but this is due to the date and time being correctly recorded in the same cell.

```
=query(TPM,"SELECT A,B,C where A contains 'Something' and A contains 'Anotherthing' and C >=  datetime '"&text($C$5,"yyyy-mm-dd 05:00:00")&"' and C < datetime '"&text($C$5,"yyyy-mm-dd 12:00:00") & "'")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: We need to see your data in a sample sheet to come up with the right answer.

Comment: I will need to create a copy as currently it is restricted to those on the my work network.

Comment: So with some of friend at work manage to get ot to work with using time as plain text. Helper colums were used on the date/time cells ={int(D2), timevalue(D2)} and further testing would allow the Split function to work too, as long as time was formatted as plain text.  ={query(TempCSV,"select A,O where A contains 'Something' and A contains 'Anotherthing' and C contains '"&$B$5&"' and O >=0.2083333333 and O <=0.5 Order By O Asc")  This eqautes to between 05:00:00 and 12:00:00.  So although working any help with the allowing time format on the helper cells and formula would be welcomed.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see your issue unless you put your formulas into a shared sheet, with some sample data and the outcome you'd like.  Working from your text description is too challenging for me.  Sorry.